How to Migrate and Sync 500GB Data from MySQL to ClickHouse and Schedule ETL Jobs?
I am currently migrating a large database (~500GB) from MySQL to ClickHouse and need guidance on how to handle the following technical challenges:
Syncing Data During Migration:
I need to keep the MySQL and ClickHouse databases in sync during the migration process. What are effective ways to achieve this, considering the size and frequency of updates?
During the migration, I want to ensure that all data is accurately transferred, especially given the differences in how MySQL and ClickHouse handle data types and queries.
I need to set up and schedule ETL jobs for both the migration and ongoing synchronization. How can I do this in a way that minimizes downtime and maintains performance?

This doesn't seem to be a question about programming. I think you want https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.

Your queation is both quite broad and confusing. Migration is a one off activity. Keeping two databases in sync is an ongoing activity. Which one are you after? Most of the tasks you need to do as part of migration or synchronisation can be done through ETL tools. What is the one, well-researched, non-duplicate, programming related question that you face in your task you need our help with?

First i need to Schedule a ETL job in clickhouse from mysql databse to clickouse

That's not really a programming task. All ooerating systems come with scheduling components and there are dozens of other apps that can manage scheduled jobs across multiple operating systems. Find the one that works the best for you. Asking us to recommend a product is explicitly off topic here on SO.
